# Oauth2 Python Package Twitter Authentication without Entering PIN

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am trying to setup this Twitter authorization without having the user to enter the pin in our screen but I am having trouble getting the correct setup I am always directed to enter the PIN. trying to use and follow this package https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Here is my current code

```
env = Environment(loader = PackageLoader('buzzient','tmpl'))
template = env.get_template('authtwitter.html')
tmpldict = {}

#SETUP TWITTER AUTHORIZATION OBJECT
consumer_key = '######################'
consumer_secret = '##############################'
request_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
access_token_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
authorize_url = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

#get request token
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
if resp['status'] != '200':
        raise Exception("Invalid Response %s." %resp['status'])

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

tmpldict['twitauthurl'] = "%s?oauth_token=%s" % ( authorize_url, request_token['oauth_token'] )
qargs=buzzientlib.urlparse_qs(self.request.url,True,False)

t = template.render(tmpldict)
self.response_body = str(t)
```

The template just includes a link to twitauthurl

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop application?  If desktop, you'll either need to settle for out-of-band PIN authorization or implement a way to handle the callback URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched packages to Tweepy and followed this example

http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html